# Internal Server Error, rather than raised AuthError response from Auth0

Tags: python, flask, auth0, flask-restful

I have my flask-restful app.py which contains all of my main functions.  I have created a server.py file as instructed from here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python

In my app.py file from server i import AuthError and requires_auth.  I have then put @requires_auth in front of my functions.

When I have a valid jwt, it works perfectly.  When the jwt is not valid it fails.  Failing is good, because the requests shouldn't work.  But the response i get from my api is "Internal Server Error" rather than the detailed response in the raise AuthError section in the server.py file.

I get 2 errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ME\code\server.py", line 88, in decorated
    issuer="https://"+AUTH0_DOMAIN+"/"
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\jose\jwt.py", line 150, in decode
    options=defaults)
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\jose\jwt.py", line 457, in _validate_claims
    _validate_exp(claims, leeway=leeway)
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\jose\jwt.py", line 299, in _validate_exp
    raise ExpiredSignatureError('Signature has expired.')
jose.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError: Signature has expired.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ME\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ME\code\server.py", line 92, in decorated
    "description": "token is expired"}, 401)
server.AuthError: ({'code': 'token_expired', 'description': 'token is expired'}, 401)
```

How do i get the AuthError as the response to the call, rather than just my Internal Server Error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with this specific tutorial in Auth0, it instructs you to include the error handler in `auth.py`:

```
@app.errorhandler(AuthError)
def handle_auth_error(ex):
    response = jsonify(ex.error)
    response.status_code = ex.status_code
    return response
```

Instead, you have to include this handler in your `app.py`, where you actually use `@requires_auth`.

Notice that to do so, you need to add relevant imports:

```
from auth import AuthError
from flask import jsonify
```

Notice: To be able to import from `auth.py` you need to add an empty file `__init__.py` in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `app.config[“PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS”] = True`

Comment: i put this in my app.py file.  I get the same error, but prettier:

    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your 
    request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application. 
    </p>

Comment: Thanks for your help though @vimalloc, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Uou could maybe use an errorhandler to explicitly catch those errors and return some explicit json based on them.